# Bing image search paging - infinite scroll

Tags: ajax, image, scroll, pagination, bing

When you search for images on the Bing search engine, the result is displayed like this:

http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=stack+overflow

Notice how you can keep scrolling and scrolling and there is not "normal" paging.

My question is: How do they do this? I can see there is some ajax/javascript events happening, but the code is not easy to read. I especially would like to know how they know when an "empty box" is inside the users view port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an article about that technology :

[Eliminate paging results by using JavaScript (ala DZone)](http://www.jaisenmathai.com/blog/2008/02/18/eliminate-paging-results-by-using-javascript-ala-dzone/) : Using Javascript, prototype and PHP.

Answer (score 2):

After some searching and reading I found this very good site:

http://www.infinite-scroll.com/

It includes downloadable WordPress and jQuery -plugins and also explains pros/cons of using "Infinite scroll/autopagerize/unpaginate/endless pages"

Sample pseudo/jQuery code to load more data when user has scrolled all the way to the bottom:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
           loadMoreRows();
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This feature is often called "infinite scrolling". Searching for [infinite scroll javascript](http://www.google.com/search?q=infinite+scroll+javascript) turns up a number of articles/posts on how to do this. Some of the more interesting ones:

- [Implementing infinite scrolling with jQuery](http://ajaxian.com/archives/implementing-infinite-scrolling-with-jquery)
- [infinite-scroll.com](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/)
- [Continuous scrolling pattern using JavaScript and ASP.NET](http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=371)

Answer (score 0):

Today I found a jQuery plugin that does the same scroll as Bing/Live Search:

http://blog.yctin.com/archives/jquery-plugins-ajaxscroll/

It was designed to remove the need for Next/Previous buttons.