# Bing-like Infinite Scrolling

Tags: jquery, user-interface, javascript, javascript-framework

Does anyone know of a library, preferably for jQuery and/or JSP, that allows continuous scrolling like [Bing Images](http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=jesus&go=&form=QBIR&qs=n&sk=&sc=8-4)?

With Bing Images, if one scrolls down to the middle of the results, for example, only the results in that area are loaded, not all of the results between the middle and top of the page as is done with most infinite scrolling libraries.

I would be using this library with text results though, not images.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming u mean lazy loading and here is [one implementation of it](http://www.appelsiini.net/2007/9/lazy-load-images-jquery-plugin)

And there are many other lazy load implementations just check my friend **google**

Comment: Knowing that this is referred to as continuous/infinite scrolling with "lazy loading" is very helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: @Jack B. no problem anytime ^_^

Comment: Don't say "google it", better provide some actual links - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-should-we-deal-with-google-questions

Answer (score 0):

[Bing image search paging - infinite scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072712/bing-image-search-paging-infinite-scroll)